# Microsoft Graph API and linking to another Microsoft API that returns billing information

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

is there a way of linking the Microsoft Graph API to another Microsoft API that provides billing information about the Azure Product License Costs.

I have read that Microsoft Cost Management API may have this feature, so could you grab lets say the subscription id from Graph API and link this to the Microsoft Cost Management API or another API that tells us that this is how much the licenses cost?

Comment: Please check this document for Cost Management + Billing feature set : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/cost-management-billing-overview and for the tools to calculate  Cost Management + Billing feature set.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/cost-management-billing-overview#additional-azure-tools

Answer (score 0):

Graph API provides `subscribedSkus` endpoint to get the list of commercial subscriptions that an organization has acquired.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus
```

`SubscribedSku` resource has properties `id` (the unique identifier for the subscribed sku object) and `skuId` (the unique identifier for the service SKU).

Use `id` to call Microsoft Cost Management API

Resources:

[Subscribed SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscribedsku?view=graph-rest-1.0)